# Печать с QPrinter::HighResolution не удается

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebengine

Я реализую возможность печати отчетов  в своем проекте. Для отчетов использую HTML шаблоны, которые потом печатаю при помощи QWebEnginePage. Мне необходимо использовать высокое разрешение печати, поэтому инициализирую принтер так:

```
QPrinter printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
```

Но печать не удается - на выходе чистый лист, а в консоли:

> QImage: out of memory, returning null image

При печати с QPrinter::ScreenResolution, все удается, но качество оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: и большие у вас там картинки? приложение 32х или 64х битное? памяти хватает?

Comment: 32 бита. На печать отправляется html документ, с одним текстом и без картинок.  Посмотрел в диспетчере, в момент печати используемая память подскакивает до ~550 Мб. Обычно на уровне 20 Мб. Почему html ест так много?

Comment: размер листа не А2 случайно? как раз 550М получается...

Comment: А если специально не указывать размер листа, какой будет по умолчанию? Позже посмотрю может и A2...

Comment: Кажется размер зависит от принтера. Печатал в PDF при помощи отдельной программы (реального принтера нет) - получал описанный результат. Потом поставил другую, аналогичную программу - качество чуть хуже, но памяти меньше жрет = больше вероятность того, что напечатает.